# Finding the optimal value of g by differentiation

Tags: derivatives

I'm currently reading the book "Introduction to Information Retrieval" (http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/). Chapter 6.1 is about finding the optimal weight g for a specific function. The function given is:

$$(n_{01r}+n_{10n})g^{2}+(n_{10r}+n_{01n})(1-g)^{2}+n_{00r}+n{11n}$$

This is a positive quadratic calculation (parabole with a minimum) and by differentiating it (and looking where derivative is 0), we can find the minimum value. The book then states the derivative (optimal g value) is:

$$\frac{n_{10r}+n_{01n}}{n_{10r}+n_{10n}+n_{01r}+n_{01n}}$$

However, I can't seem to figure out how they came to this derivative. It's not necessary for the calculations that follow, but I'm still interested.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call your function $f(g)$
$$    
\begin{eqnarray}
f(g)  & = & (n_{01r}+n_{10n})g^2+(n_{10r}+n_{01n})(1−g)^2+n_{00r}+n_{11n} \\
      & = & (n_{01r}+n_{10n})g^2+(n_{10r}+n_{01n})(1−2g+g^2)+n_{00r}+n_{11n}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
and differentiate it with respect to $g$:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f'(g) & = & g(n_{01r}+n_{10n})2g + (n_{10r}+n_{01n})(2g-2)\\
      & = & 2g (n_{01r}+n_{10n}+n_{10r}+n_{01n}) - 2(n_{10r}+n_{01n}).
\end{eqnarray}
$$
In order for $f$ to assume its extremal value on $g$, its derivate there must vanish,i.e.
$$
f'(g) = 2g (n_{01r}+n_{10n}+n_{10r}+n_{01n}) - 2(n_{10r}+n_{01n}) \overset{!}{=}0,
$$ 
which yields 
$$g=\frac{n_{10r}+n_{01n}}{n_{01r}+n_{10n}+n_{10r}+n_{01n}}$$.